# Is there a way to use countifs and vlookups together?

Tags: excel, vlookup, countif

I currently have a data table that lists site names in column 1, followed by a unique associated contact in column 2 and one of three status types for that unique contact (lets say "A", "B", or "C"). Many of these sites will have multiple contacts. I am trying to determine which sites have any contacts with status "A" and list only those sites. Is there a way to combine countifs and vlookups to determine this?

Here is an example

Data Table

[image: Data Table]

Desired Table

[image: Desired Table]

Comment: I forgot to mention that the status type for that contact would be listed in column 3.

Comment: It would help if you mocked up some data and showed us visually the data setup as a table and the expected output given the test data.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I just added an example.

Comment: =IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,"New York",C:C,"Commercial"),"Yes","No")